# How to work with a file created in python inside Github Actions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, automation, boto3, github-actions

Sup guys!
I'm working on a project that creates an AWS Lex using python scripts  to create a bot.
I have scripts for the building stage, Intent creation, slots and slot types; must of them writes the corresponding ID's in a file named config.json for functional purposes.
My Teacher ask me to write a function that build the Bot only if it not exist allready, othewise must be updated.
Certainlly is not the best approach, but the following script fullfill my asignment in a local environment, creating the Bot in AWS:

```
import boto3
import json
from os.path import exists
import time

client = boto3.client('lexv2-models')
file_exists = exists('../config.json')

if file_exists:
    print('File exists, i will delete the Bot')
    with open('../config.json', 'r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)
        botIdData = config['botId']
        f.close()

    if botIdData:
        response = client.delete_bot(
            botId=botIdData,
            skipResourceInUseCheck=True
        )
        print(response)
        time.sleep(5)
        print('Bot deleted')
    
        
response = client.create_bot(
    botName='myFirstBot',
    description='A bot to query Students data',
    roleArn='arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/lambda-invoke-role',
    dataPrivacy={
        'childDirected': False
    },
    idleSessionTTLInSeconds=300,
)

botIdData = response.get('botId')

with open('../config.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(
        {
            "botId": botIdData,
        }, f, indent=4)
    f.close()
```

And this is my trigger:

```
name: LexCI
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feat/updatingScripts
jobs: 
  build: 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest 
    steps: 
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }} 
          aws-region: us-east-1
      - name: checkout repo content 
        uses: actions/checkout@v2 
      - name: create bot
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2 
        with: 
          python-version: 3.8 
      - name: execute py script 
        run: | 
          pip install boto3
          python3 scripts/botCreation/createBot.py
```

My problem is, when i run the scripts in GitHub actions, the config.json file that I'm using to check if the Bot exist isn't builded in the folder directory as it does locally ( i did some research and it seems related to GITHUB_WORKSPACE ).
That's why I'm asking for some help / tips. I don´t know how to do it and I'm kinda stuck in here with the logic that I build.
Can be this issue be resolved with the Python script? Or do I have to make changes in the .yml file in Github to achieve this?

Sadly I cant share the Repository link since is from the academy where am I studying and its private. Anyway the error is related just to the createBot.py script. If you run it locally ( just the python script! remember to add a valid arn ) the bot will be created in Amazon, you run it again and the script will erase the old bot and creates a new one with the diferent Id ( check the config.json created ) Now, if you run the .yml file at GitHub actions the method to "delete" the bot it's passed by because in GitHub the config.json isn't stored in the repository folders. Then the .yml file will bypass the delete Bot method ( since the config.json doesn't exist in the repo directory) and will try to create it, but how it's allready exist, will throw an error.

Grateful in advance for your time guys!
Best regards: Martín

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Could you share the repository files/directories structure in the question please? 

Comment: Tnx for your quick response guys! I've edited the post, please check it out

Answer (score 1):

After trying different approachs, I've ended uploading the config.json file to an S3 bucket and reading values from there